# \appendixname does not appear

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, appendix

Simply, for some reason, the appendix names do not appear, neither in the titles nor in the TOC. See the attached pictures.[image] And also:

[image]

As you can see, instead of "Appendix. 1" or "A.1.", there is just a ".1".
Sadly I cannot provide a minimum working example because I am using the "mimosis" class based on KOMA-script, and I am not knowledgeable enough as to delve in the class defining document.
I am using, however the appendix package

```
\documentclass{mimosis}
\usepackage[toc, title, titletoc]{appendix}
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix}

\begin{document}
\begin{appendices}

\section{Description of the Data}
Everything is self-explanatory.

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

Any ideas I could try?

Comment: The `mimosis` class is based on `scrbook`. So if you replace `\section` with `\chapter`, the Appendix name will probably appear. Not tested as the class you are using is not in TeX Live, sorry.

Comment: That was exactly it. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One need to set `\setcounter{chapter}{1}` after begin of appendix.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage[toc, title, titletoc]{appendix}
%\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\begin{document}
%\phantomsection\pdfbookmark[1]{\contentsname}{Contents}
\tableofcontents

\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter{Methodology}


\begin{appendices}
\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{1}}
\setcounter{chapter}{1}
\chapter*{Appendices}

\section{Description of the Data}
Everything is self-explanatory.

\end{appendices}

\chapter*{Bibliography}
\phantomsection\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image: toc]